# ¿Cómo establezco un valor con patch o value con FormArray?

Tags: angular

Tengo la siguiente definición de mi formulario:

```
public dotacionForm:FormGroup = new FormGroup({
  dotaciones: new FormArray([
    new FormGroup({
      nombre: new FormControl(null),
      stock: new FormControl({value:null, disabled: true}),
      n_id_material: new FormControl(null),  
      n_id_talla_material:new FormControl(null),
      n_cantidad:new FormControl(null),
      n_id_tipo_dotacion:new FormControl(null),                             
      n_id_obs:new FormControl(null)  
    })
  ])
});
```

¿Cómo establezco valores para n_cantidad y stock a través de un evento en mi código typescript, busque en la documentación pero no se entiende.

Comment: Tienes un group con un array con un único elemento dentro que es otro form group... ¿Por qué tanta complejidad?

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar `setValue(value)` y `at(index)` según [Angular FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#setvalue) y [Angular FormArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#methods), en el caso que quieras asignarle un valor a un campo en específico utiliza un **get**, posteriormente el método **at** antes y posteriormente el **setValue** de la siguiente forma:

```
(this.dotacionForm.get('dotaciones') as FormArray).at(0).get('n_cantidad').setValue(15);
(this.dotacionForm.get('dotaciones') as FormArray).at(0).get('stock').setValue(20);
```

El casteo que se hace a formArray es solamente para que no te salga el error en `at()`.

Para obtener los valores de los mismos puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
console.log(this.dotacionForm.value.dotaciones[0].n_cantidad);
console.log(this.dotacionForm.value.dotaciones[0].stock);
```

Espero te sirva. Saludos ;)

Comment: más bien tendría que hacer algo como `this.dotacionForm.get('dotaciones').at(0).get('n_cantidad').setValue(...)`

Comment: Huy que paso con el código creo que no estaba con el array XDXD tienes mucha razon ahora lo corrijo

Comment: this.dotacionForm.get('dotaciones').at(index).get('n_cantidad').setValue(15), trate de hacer eso, pero sale error: property "at" doesnt exist sale

Comment: intenta casteando a formArray para que no te salga ese error

Answer (score 0):

una ultima consulta, como obtengo ese valor de stock desde typecript, desde typescript, intente esto:

(this.dotacionForm.get('dotaciones') as FormArray).at(index).get('stock').value()

pero sale error, saludos gracias

Comment: Esta es la respuesta:(this.dotacionForm.get('dotaciones') as FormArray).at(index).get('stock').value

Comment: Saludos nuevamente, reservamos esta sección solamente para respuestas. Puedes modificar tu pregunta nuevamente o realizar una nueva pregunta para lo que necesitas. de todas formas modifique mi respuesta para lo que solicitas, porfavor elimina ésto que agregaste.